# Should I reword the original question after discovering that the original question had false assumptions?

Tags: discussion

**Summary**

So I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640242/r-how-to-return-full-output-in-console-no-truncation) question earlier today that has a rather interesting timeline.

1. My initial question assumed it was a truncation issue so I worded it as *"How to return full output in console (no truncation)"*
2. I unknowingly gave a bad example; I replaced the actual field names with dummy names, which masked the actual issue (special character processing)
3. People weren't able to reproduce my original issue (truncation)
4. Upon the troubleshooting suggestions (to reproduce a sample of the csv file) and comments, I realized the real issue was special character processing

**Question**

My question is, how can I edit this question so it's useful to future readers running into what I experienced?  Should I keep the edits as is or should I reword say my original question?

Comment: The main thing is not to invalidate any existing answers. If you've discovered your real problem isn't what you stated in the question, you should ask and self-answer a separate question to help future readers.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: So, bottom line: self-answer your question to show that you had false assumptions, then ask the real question as a new question (assuming it hasn't already been asked), and link the old question to the new one.